# Symfony - List of form fields in event

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

Is possible to get some list of fields in FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA?

I need edit entity which I put to Form by Event. Entity contains PersistCollection which I need transform to ArrayObject.

I would like created on automatic for many entities. I need list of fields (names) for data mapping.

My idea:

```
$fields = $event->getFormFields();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    dump($field); --> return 'name'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to achieve, but yes, you can get all child forms from parent form easily:

You can either use:

```
foreach ($event->getForm()->all() as $childForm) {
    // ...
}
```

or, since Symfony Form implements IteratorAggregate interface:

```
foreach ($event->getForm() as $childForm) {
}
```